# alternatives to jpivot?

Tags: ria, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, olap-cube

JPivot, even with all it's functionality, seems a bit outdated...

last version at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpivot/ is from 2008-03-17...

is there any other lightweight client olap cube browser, that could take advantage of modern RIA kits, like GWT, smartGWT, ZK, ExtJs, etc....?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just found this

http://www.jpalo.com

demo:

stunning demo: (built on ExtJs, I think)

[demo](http://www.jpalo.com/en/palo_pivot.php?sent=yes&option[]=OpenApp&option[]=ViewTabs&option[]=AutoLogin&option[]=AutoUser&option[]=OpenView1&option[]=Toolbar1&option[]=HorizonalAxis1&option[]=Save1&option[]=POV1&option[]=VerticalAxis1&option[]=Toolbar3&option[]=HorizonalAxis3&option[]=POV3&option[]=VerticalAxis3#PaloWebDemo)

http://www.jpalo.com/en/palo_pivot.php?sent=yes&option[]=OpenApp&option[]=ViewTabs&option[]=AutoLogin&option[]=AutoUser&option[]=OpenView1&option[]=Toolbar1&option[]=HorizonalAxis1&option[]=Save1&option[]=POV1&option[]=VerticalAxis1&option[]=Toolbar3&option[]=HorizonalAxis3&option[]=POV3&option[]=VerticalAxis3#PaloWebDemo

another example with jpalo at http://www.jedox.com/en/home/overview.html

demo: http://paloweb.jedox.com/

--

here's another on (on alpha release, the former PAT - pentaho analysis tool at http://code.google.com/p/pentahoanalysistool/)

http://www.analytical-labs.com/

demo: http://demo.analytical-labs.com

--

here's another one...

http://azada.sourceforge.net/

--

this one seems promising, but stagnant...

http://code.google.com/p/stpivot/

--

very complete demo featuring many of the aforementioned products...

http://sample.stratebi.es/

user: demo

password: stratebi2010

--
spagoBI demo featuring jpivot and jpalo cube browsers

http://spagobi.eng.it/SpagoBI/servlet/AdapterHTTP?PAGE=LoginPage&NEW_SESSION=TRUE

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add my own project to the list :

http://mysticfall.github.com/pivot4j/

It was specifically designed for such purpose. Notable difference with JPivot however, is that it's not a full application like JPivot or Saiku but a library.

But you should be able to build your own GUI without much effort as shown with the JSF based sample application :

http://mysticfall.github.com/pivot4j/example.html

Comment: Mysticfall has now created a BI server plugin for this too!

Answer (score 4):

This post is old but now, you can try [Saiku](http://analytical-labs.com/)

Answer (score 3):

[Webpivottable.com](http://webpivottable.com) is a pure javascript pivot table solution. No dependence on any particular back end technology.

Here is their [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo)

Saiku is the replacement of jpivot but still a java backend solution. The support is not free now although it's still an open source project. You need buy their paid support. The old free forum has gone.

Comment: That's a really nice tool. It's pretty amazing the lack of widgets like this. I would presume that there would be tons of open source, client side, controls like this.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for something similar to plug into GWT - iCCube has a GWT pivot table component, and SmartClient also has a pivot component.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try this:
http://www.flexmonster.com/demo-all-in-one/

Flexmonster can use Mondrian, MS Analysis Service or CSV files as data source

Comment: It looks nice, is flash based.

Comment: It also has an HTML5 version now.

Answer (score 0):

[Quartet FS](http://www.quartetfs.com) (the makers of ActivePivot the real-time, in-memory analytics solution) also develop [ActivePivot Live](http://quartetfs.com/en/products/activepivot-live), a professional web-based OLAP frontend that supports MDX and XMLA. ActivePivot Live is a commercial software. It is based on GWT and designed to be extendible.

Comment: I have bad experience with Quartet FS.
There are no live demo on your website and I was rejected to get access to it by your unfriendly support team.